# Board Games development online course

Tags: game-development

Are there any online courses like codecademy.com or teamtreehouse.com for Board Games development? Or something similar where you can learn BG development? Also if you know any other useful resources like books, videos and similar things, please share

Comment: I don't know about online courses, but there are a number of books on the topic.  If you want to broaden your question to include those, I'll suggest some.

Comment: Best way to learn; play many different board games, including ones you wouldn't normally like.

Comment: Highly recommend the book "The Art of Game Design"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a specific board or card game.

Comment: @DrunkCynic I don't think that's a good metric for closing. There are a number of questions on the site that don't refer to a specific board game. "Designing board games" is on-topic for this site, and the OP is asking for objective information. This seems to fit all of the criteria I can find for acceptable questions, except that it may generate a list.

Comment: @SocioMatt Then there is some ambiguity in the Help Center topic "What topics can I ask about here?", which has a paragraph starting with "For a question to be on topic, it must relate to a game that is on topic..."  That was my guidepost for the metric.

Comment: @DrunkCynic In rereading the entire page on the Help Center, I think that "a game" is meant to refer to games that meet the four criteria under "How do we define board games?" I agree this is confusing when taken out of context. If we assumed that questions had to relate to a game that already existed, then design would be off-topic, which would contradict the first sentence of [What topics can I ask about here?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Reopening - There is no requirement that a question be about only one game.

Comment: Thank you everyone :) @bwarner I boraden question, can you suggest books please? tnx

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is essentially the same as a game recommendation question, which is [off-topic for this site](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/3389).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it as asking for school advice

Answer (score 7):

Here are a couple EdX options. The first is about game design (both board and computer games). The second focuses on games meant for education.

https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-game-design-mitx-11-126x
https://www.edx.org/course/design-development-games-learning-mitx-11-127x